# Slicing an array and converting from RTL / LTR

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

I have an array of elements, the length changes but its always divisable by 8 (8,16,24,32,40,48..etc).

I am trying to slice off the first 8 elements, return them.
Then slice off the next 8 elements and return them in reverse.

And repeat until the array is empty (RTL then LTR then RTL..etc).

I am unsure how to iterate and keep track.

```
const print = (value) => document.write(value);

rtl = true
elements = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]

const sliceArr = (arr, cnt) => {
    arr = arr.slice(0,cnt)
    if(rtl) return arr
    else {
      rtl = !rtl; // toggle rtl
    }
}

tmpArray = []

tmpArray = sliceArr(elements, 8)
print(tmpArray)
```

Desired output

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9
17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to create a new array with a length of `Math.ceil(elements.length / 8)`. In the callback, get the current index, and get the slice from the `elements` array. If `i % 2` is 0 return the slice, but if it's an odd index, return the reverse of the slice:

```js
const elements = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]

const result = Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(elements.length / 8) }, (_, i) => {
  const arr = elements.slice(i * 8, (i + 1) * 8)
  return i % 2 ? arr.reverse() : arr
})

console.log(result.join('\n'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could slice the array and check the direction.

```js
const slice = (array, size, direction) => {
    var result = [],
        i = 0,
        temp;
        
    while (i < array.length) {
        var temp = array.slice(i, i +=size);
        if (direction) temp.reverse();
        direction = !direction;
        result.push(temp);
    }
    return result;
}

slice([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24], 8, false).map(a => console.log(...a));
```